# Adding elements to a list in R (in nested lists)

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list l3 as:

```
l1<- as.list(c(1,2,3,4,5))
l1

l2<- as.list(c(6,7,8,9,10))
l2

l3<- list(l1,l2)
l3
```

l3 shows as:

```
> l3
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 4

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 7

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 8

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 9

[[2]][[5]]
[1] 10
```

I need to add a third list l4 to l3 such that l3 becomes:

```
[[1]][[1]]
    [1] 1

to

[[2]][[5]]
    [1] 10


[[3]][[1]]
    [1] 30

[[3]][[2]]
    [1] 32

[[3]][[3]]
    [1] 33

[[3]][[4]]
    [1] 34

[[3]][[5]]
    [1] 35
```

where l4 was:

```
l4<- as.list(c(31,32,33,34,35))
```

how do I accomplish it? I've tried `(c)`, `list`, even explicitly put the arguments and got an `out of bounds error`. What can I use to get this done?

Comment: Please show reproducible code example of what you tried.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It works with `append` and `list`:

```
append(l3, list(l4))
```

The result:

```
> str(append(l3, list(l4)))
List of 3
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 3
  ..$ : num 4
  ..$ : num 5
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ : num 6
  ..$ : num 7
  ..$ : num 8
  ..$ : num 9
  ..$ : num 10
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ : num 31
  ..$ : num 32
  ..$ : num 33
  ..$ : num 34
  ..$ : num 35
```

Comment: It worked with this, but I tried it with another piece of code, it didn't. Too bad, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know what you have tried with `c`, but it works

```
c(l3,list(l4))
```

PS: `append`  is a wrapper of `c` to insert in a specific index, (see after argument  )